# Prevent multiple access of servlet in my application

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

given below is the url configured as an autosys job .This calls the servlet given below.Can anyone suggest me how to protect this method "psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();" being called continously with improper data modification by each time this url is pressed continously say 10 times.I want it to be accessed only one thread at a time.

I know i have to use a synchronized method or block ..am not sure on how to..since am not that familiar with threads.

```
http://mydomain:11000/dorf/HRDORFScriptServlet?script=hrFeed


public class HRDORFScriptServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HRDORFScriptServlet.class);
private final String script = "script";

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    performTask(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    performTask(arg0, arg1);
}

 /** Execute the servlet.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws ServletException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {

    DorfUser dorfUser = DorfSessionUtils.getDorfUser(request.getSession());
    HRDorfFeedServiceWrapper psServiceWrapper = new HRDorfFeedServiceWrapper(dorfUser);
    String reqParam = request.getParameter(script);
    if(reqParam.equals("hrFeed")){
    try{
        psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();           
    }
    catch(ServiceException se){
        log.error("Error While calling HRFeed Service : "+se.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Error While calling HRFeed Service : "+e.getMessage());
    }

    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the functionality of `psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed()` to a simple class that implements Runnable.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable
{
    public void run() 
    {
        psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();
    }
}
```

Then create an ExecutorService with a fixed thread pool size of 1.

```
ExecutorService psServiceRunner = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Everytime the servlet is called, I would post an instance of MyTask to this one.

```
psServiceRunner.execute(new MyTask());
```

This will

1. not block your servlet caller.
2. ensure that only one servlet can run the method at any point of time.

Answer (score 2):

```
synchronized(this){ 
 psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();     
}
```

But this will lead to Bottleneck since your servlet will stop responding until  `psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();` is executed by current thread.

You can also you [ReetrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) if you are using Java 5

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

```
   private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();//Declare it
```

Use it like below

```
 lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
 try {
   psServiceWrapper.processHRFeed();
 } finally {
   lock.unlock()
 }
```

Comment: Serializing access as mentioned in this post will indeed solve your issue but at the expense of your application's liveliness. Your actual problem is that processHRFeed() method is not concurrent. If performance makes sense in your project and if you have access to the method's implementation (that is if you can modify it), i would suggest investigating if you could re-engineer the method in order to run safely by concurrent threads.